# Adding SSO Login for Backpack admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a project in production that consists of an admin panel (using backpack) and an Angular webapp. The client wants to use ADFS login for both sites and I'm struggling a little bit on how to implement it for the administration panel.

Regarding the webapp (angular) I had no trouble, I receive a field on the ADFS callback that is associated on DB with the user and I just return the info needed just as when the user makes the "usual" api login.

I guess my problem is I don't have full grasp on how Laravel/Backpack authentification/login works 100% and so I'm unable to implement this new Login.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd scrap the Backpack auth entirely and build my own. Trying to make a hybrid (or change the Backpack auth to fit your needs) will probably take more time AND be more difficult to maintain in the long run, so not worth it.

There's nothing wrong in saying "ok, this part of Backpack isn't what I need" and doing your own thing. In fact, Backpack tries to stay out of the way when it's not being helpful, so there's an easy way to disable its auth and replace it with yours.

In `config/backpack/base.php` you should change a few configs, particularly the ones below:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Set this to false if you would like to use your own AuthController and PasswordController
    // (you then need to setup your auth routes manually in your routes.php file)
    'setup_auth_routes' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // The guard that protects the Backpack admin panel.
    // If null, the config.auth.defaults.guard value will be used.
    'guard' => 'backpack',

    // The password reset configuration for Backpack.
    // If null, the config.auth.defaults.passwords value will be used.
    'passwords' => 'backpack',

];
```